# how to include a JSON object in a AJAX Post with beforeSend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object with several params. In my ajax post, I would like to include this var json along with the settings.data object. But I want to include it in a way where it stays an object..

I have:

```
var json = // JSON OBJECT
// I try to convert it for the query string
var readytogo = decodeURIComponent($.param(json));;
```

Then in the ajax before send I have:

```
settings.data += '&extrainfo=' + readytogo;
```

but this is causing all the JSON object's values to no longer be grouped under a extrainfo array?

How do you pass along an array? Thanks

Comment: You don't have a "JSON object" because JSON is always a string, not an object. Are you saying you have a JavaScript object (an array?) that you want to stringify to JSON, and then you want the JSON representation of your object to be included in your ajax request as a single parameter `&extrainfo=`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var readytogo = $.param({'extrainfo':json});
   settings.data += '&' + readytogo;
```